# How to know that my current location is from a GPS or wifi

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using Google API for retrieving current location, and I got the current location by set `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`.

In my app I want to know my location is from GPS or WIFI. How do I check that ?
I've used `location.getProvider()`. But, I got only "fused".

Is there any way to check or I have to use `getAccuracy`?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine a location source in this way

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
...
...
private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, networkLocationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, gpsLocationListener);
}

//Network
private LocationListener networkLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Location set by network
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int status, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};

//GPS
private LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Location set by gps
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int status, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};
```

}